# How to create a NewLetter in sharepoint

Tags: web-part, newsletter

I need to create a News Letter that sends E-mail to the corresponding users who have subscribed to the newsletter.And the newsletter template must be attached with 4 other lists.And the changes in that lists must be send as an the text and send email monthly.

Comment: I have tried with one list,so that the changes made in that list will be send as an email through workflows.But I need 4 lists data to be send

Comment: @user48242   [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianpal/archive/2008/12/30/create-and-manage-newsletters-with-sharepoint.aspx]